# PHP creating large xml with same options but different values each time

Tags: xml, templates, large-data

I have a website that has a large form (50+ fields).

Each field is mandatory. After the form is submitted, I need to put all values into an xml file.

The XML file will always have the same elements, but with different values.

I've been trying to find the best way to create them and I thought there would be some sort of templating for XML.

What is the best way to do this?

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$m_content_tag = $doc->createElement("m_content");
$m_content_tag = $message_tag->appendChild($m_content_tag);
$b_control_tag = $doc->createElement("b_control");
$b_control_tag = $m_content_tag->appendChild($b_control_tag);
$b_control_tag->appendChild($doc->createElement('service_provider_reference_number'));
$b_control_tag->appendChild($doc->createElement('intermediary_case_reference_number'));
```

For each element, which is getting quite hard to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Symfony you could use [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) to handle the rendering your XML template. This will let you keep all the XML in a separate file then you can just pass an assoc array of your validated fields to [TWIG's](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) render method and [TWIG](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/documentation) will handle the rest. You can even break down the different XML sections into different files and include them dynamically as blocks.

**XML Template:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <field_1>{{ var1 }}</field_1>
    <field_2>{{ var2 }}</field_2>
    <field_3>
             {% for subvar in var3 %}
                 <subfield_3>{{ subvar }}</subfield_3>
             {% endfor %}
    </field_3>
</root>
```

**PHP Code:**

```
//Validate fields into assoc array
$fields['var1'] = 'Some Value';
$fields['var2'] = 'Some other Value';
$fields['var3'] = array(1,2,3,4);

//Set up TWIG
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('/path/to/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => '/path/to/compilation_cache',
));

//Render template
echo $twig->render('xml_template.xml', $fields);
```

Comment: @CharliePrynn No Problem, just glad I could help out the community.

Answer (score 1):

Why not to use simple string templates like this?

```
$template = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <field_1>${field_1}</field1>
    <field_2>${field_2}</field2>
    <field_3>
        <subfield_3>${subfield_3}</subfield_3>
    </field3>
</root>'
```

And populate it with values by replacing ${field_name} with concrete values.

Comment: The XML file is large, I think doing it like this, will become a bit of a mess.

Comment: You can store it as xml file on disk and load it into string with file_get_contents function. Then populate it with values and save as result xml.

Answer (score 0):

DOMDocument objects are good, but for large XML files, you may prefer to use [XMLWriter](http://php.net/manual/book.xmlwriter.php) which will allow you to write an XML file as a stream instead of keeping it in memory.

Instead of `createElement` and `appendChild`, you will need to use `startElement` and `endElement` and/or `writeElement`.

So instead of:

```
$m_content_tag = $doc->createElement("m_content");
$m_content_tag = $message_tag->appendChild($m_content_tag);
$b_control_tag = $doc->createElement("b_control");
$b_control_tag = $m_content_tag->appendChild($b_control_tag);
$b_control_tag->appendChild($doc->createElement('service_provider_reference_number'));
$b_control_tag->appendChild($doc->createElement('intermediary_case_reference_number'));
```

You will need to write:

```
$writer = new XMLWriter();
$writer->openURI('myfile.xml')
$writer->startElement('messsage_tag');
$writer->startElement("m_content");
$writer->startElement("b_control");
$wrtier->writeElement('service_provider_reference_number', $value1);
$wrtier->writeElement('intermediary_case_reference_number',  $value2);
$writer->endElement("b_control");
$writer->endElement("m_content");
$writer->endElement('messsage_tag');
```

This is more long to write, but this will take less memory to work.

By the way, if you only have to deal with 50 fields, I think that it's small enough to continue using DOMDocument.

Using DOMDocument will permit you to use [XSLTProcessor](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/xsltprocessor.construct.php) which will allow you to use 
[XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/default.asp) files as template files for XML.

This can be done this way:

```
$xsl = new XSLTProcessor();
$xsldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xsldoc->load($xsl_filename);
$xsl->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);

$xmldoc = new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load($xml_filename);
echo $xsl->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

But this can achieved only to transform DOMDocument object into something else. You can't, for exemple, transform an array to a DOM by using `XSLTProcessor`;